# Error de conección de Web a Android o iOS en Snack

Tags: nodejs, json, ios, fetch, expo

Me slata un error al cambiar de WEB (donde sí funciona y registra los datos en la BD) a Android o iOS

El error es el siguiente:
Error al hacer el fetch: Error: "Network request failed" in @[snack internals] << @[snack internals] << p@[snack internals] << callTimers@[snack internals]

Y mi código es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, Kevin, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? Por favor, incluye tu código como texto formateado en lugar de como imagen.